# How to plot column chart with bars for 2 categories next to each other?

Tags: pandas, plot, column-chart

I need to draw chart like this one. I have 2 categories, named 0 and 1. I want to plot "age vs amount" etc with 2 categories compared next to each other.

[image: k]

```
df.groupby(by = df['target']).plot(kind='bar')
```

but it draws 2 separate charts.

Answer (score 0):

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html

You can find the sub-plot documentation here for making a bar chart like your requirement